# Can I grab the height of an unrelated element that has a dynamic height with Sass?

Tags: css, sass

I have 2 unrelated elements: `#A` and `#B` (in terms of hierarchy). `#A` does not have a predefined height. I would like `#B` to end up being the height of `#A` minus `325px`.

I know Sass can handle operations, but I am unsure of how to query the height of `#A` - is that even possible?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: @ITChristian Yes. But if possible, I would prefer not to.

Comment: @ITChristian Let me make sure it works, I promise I will mark you as accepted if this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I think is not possible to get a element height with SASS (i'm not an expert in sass, but I couldn't find any option).

I recommend you to do this with JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/9DcYn/2/

```
window.onload = fixHeight();
function fixHeight() {
    var divh = document.getElementById('leftdiv').offsetHeight;
    var divhnum = new Number(divh);
    var setheight = (divhnum - 325);
    document.getElementById('rightdiv').style.height = setheight + 'px';
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: This doesn't look too bulky. Let me give it a shot.

Comment: and the JavaScript code must have his tags <script> MY SCRIPT CODE ABOVE </script>

Comment: Dang - slow down. It just took me a little bit to get it implemented. I wasn't having any issues, I just wanted to make sure it solved my particular case. Which it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with CSS or SASS, plain easy with jQuery:

```
$('#b').outerHeight( $('#a').outerHeight() - 325 );
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ulimon/2/edit